# Why bicycles' rims are bent after winter?

Tags: material-science, viscosity, solid-mechanics

I've noticed that the rims of many bicycles which are parked in the street during the whole winter are heavily bent. I'm wondering what causes this deformation? Typically, this happens to rather cheap bikes.

A natural guess would be that their rims are made from alloys which lose rigidity after numerous significant temperature changes. But, to be honest, this doesn't sound very convincing since the stress is rather small when the bike is just staying motionless all the time.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this. Asking how such stuff works is very much on-topic, in my opinion. I don't see a question like "How do I prevent this?"; _that_would be engineering.

Comment: Is this physics? I'm thinking that "in the street during the whole winter" could explain everything by itself, what with cars and even snow plows, particularly if the bikes are hidden by snow.